# Set a different disabled color for two different JButtons? (UIManager.getDefaults changes both buttons)

Tags: java, swing, colors, jbutton

I am trying to make one button have a disabled text of Red and the other disabled text of Blue, but when using the following code all it does is just make them both Red.

Is there a simple way of fixing this?

```
UIManager.getDefaults().put("Button.disabledText",Color.BLUE);
button1.setEnabled(false);
UIManager.getDefaults().put("Button.disabledText",Color.RED);
button2.setEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 2):

The appearance is determined by the `ButtonUI` specified in the user's chosen Look & Feel. If you are creating your own L&F, you can override [`getDisabledTextColor()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/plaf/metal/MetalButtonUI.html#getDisabledTextColor%28%29). This related [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5169647/when-does-a-jpanel-paint-or-repaint-its-child-components/5170911#5170911) may suggest how to proceed. While it is technically possible, I'm not sure how users would interpret the difference.

Although it's tangential to your needs, descendants of `JTextComponent` offer [`setDisabledTextColor()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#setDisabledTextColor%28java.awt.Color%29) for this purpose.

Comment: *"While it is technically possible, I'm not sure how users would interpret the difference."*  Just because we have the technology, does not mean we should use it.

Comment: current JVM instance has only one UIManager +1

Answer (score 2):

As thrashgod says, the button's `ButtonUI` controls the disabled text color. Luckily, you can change a button's `ButtonUI`:

```
button1.setUI(new MetalButtonUI() {
    protected Color getDisabledTextColor() {
        return Color.BLUE;
    }
});
button1.setEnabled(false);
button2.setUI(new MetalButtonUI() {
    protected Color getDisabledTextColor() {
        return Color.RED;
    }
});
button2.setEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    /**
 * Sets the Color of the specified button.  Sets the button text Color to the inverse of the Color.
 *
 * @param button The button to set the Color of.
 * @param color The color to set the button to.
 */
private static void setButtonColor(JButton button, Color color)
{
    // Sets the button to the specified Color.
    button.setBackground(color);
    // Sets the button text to the inverse of the button Color.
    button.setForeground(new Color(color.getRGB() ^ Integer.MAX_VALUE));
}
```

Here's some code I found on

http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/java/threads/9791

Hope it helps!!! I really didn't understand the question :P

Comment: I am trying to change the text while the button is disabled(button.setEnabled(false)).  I believe the code you gave me will only affect the color when the buttons are enabled(button.setEnabled(true)).