# What is the border type of the digichat login button?

Tags: java, swing, awt, jbutton

I tried many methods to make a JButton such as the "Connect" button which appears in the digichat applet,

but I failed! Oh, I want know: What is the border type of this button? I attached a photo to explain the button; can any one help me with ideas, or tell me how to create it?

[image: screenshot digichat connect-button]

Answer (score 3):

It may very well be a custom border, implemented entirely from scratch or a [`CompoundBorder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/border/CompoundBorder.html) which is a combination of several standard borders.

There's no way to tell how they have solved it based on the screen shot.

Comment: Probably the best way to simulate an old Mac OS 9 L&F [button](http://earthnet.net/support/images/dialup/mac_os9_long/dialup_os9_20.gif)

Comment: See also [*How to Use Borders*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html).

Answer (score 3):

The appearance is defined by the old [Mac OS 9 Look & Feel](https://www.google.com/#q=mac+os+9+images), as shown here:

[image: Mac OS 9 dialog]

Although it's a considerably more laborious alternative, you can implement your own `ButtonUI`, as illustrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5755124/230513) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5170911/230513).